# Check If File Created Within Last X Hours

Tags: c#

How can I check if a file has been created in the last x hours? like 23 hours etc. Using C# 3.0.

Note: This must also work if I create the file now, then the file will be seconds old not an hour old yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use:

```
System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(filename);
```

To get the creation time of the file, see [GetCreationTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime.aspx) for more details and examples.

Then you can do something like:

```
public bool IsBelowThreshold(string filename, int hours)
{
     var threshold = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-hours);
     return System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(filename) <= threshold;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be >= threshold to signify the time is greater or newer than the threshold?

Answer (score 12):

Something like this...

```
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\MyFile.txt");
        bool myCheck = fileinfo.CreationTime > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-23);
```

Comment: You combine the last 2 lines into something like
<pre>
bool myCheck = fileinfo.CreationTime > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-23);
</pre>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. noticed a typo: fileInfo in the second line has no capital 'i'

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`File.GetCreationTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime.aspx) and compare to the current time:

```
private static bool IsFileOlder(string fileName, TimeSpan thresholdAge)
{
    return (DateTime.Now - File.GetCreationTime(fileName)) > thresholdAge;
}

// used like so:
// check if file is older than 23 hours
bool oldEnough = IsFileOlder(@"C:\path\file.ext", new TimeSpan(0, 23, 0, 0));
// check if file is older than 23 milliseconds
bool oldEnough = IsFileOlder(@"C:\path\file.ext", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 23));
```

Comment: I like that this potentially avoids the creation of a whole FileInfo object just to read a single property.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class and the [`CreationTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx) property.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\myfile.txt");
bool check = (DateTime.Now - fi.CreationTime).TotalHours < 23;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("c:\\file.txt");
    if (fi.CreationTime.AddHours(23) >= DateTime.Now)
    {
        //created within the last 23 hours
    }
```